# backbone js view how to display

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am new to backbone js and somehow i managed to read the json file and get the data to the controller. Now how do i pass the data to my view. I am ok if the data is displayed with ul tags.All i want is to display the data from json file.

```
(function($){
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
        collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url:'services.json',
            model:model,
            parse:function(response){    
                console.log(response.values); //Working
                return response.values;
            }
        });

     var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.

initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods

   this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
},

     render: function(eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(){

            $(this.el).append();  //How to display the values here

       }, this);



          return this;
        }

  });

source = new collection();
var listView = new ListView({model:source});
 source.fetch({
    success: function (values) {
        var data = values.toJSON();
        console.log(data); //Working
        listView.render();
    }
});

 })(jQuery);
```

**json**

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "name A",
            "location": "location A"
        },
        {
            "name": "name B",
            "location": "location B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code 
1) you shouldn't pass collection as model, change to

```
var listView = new ListView({collection:source});
```

2) dont call render multiple times, it should called after ajax so remove render from view's initialize

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
},
```

3)appending to dom

```
    render: function(eventName) {
            this.collection.each(function(model) {
             this.$el.append('li'+model.get('name');+'<li>');
        }
   }
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I am looking some tutorials that will have practical approach. If you know any websites, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for extending your hand.